# Arduino. Why does my code work with a delay

Tags: arduino

I have written a code that for some reason only works when I place a delay. It is supposed to be a traffic light

```
 int switchState = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT); // red light
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT); // yellow light
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); // green light
  pinMode(2, INPUT);  // button, when pressed lights switch
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
  switchState = digitalRead(2);
  if(switchState == HIGH){  
    if(digitalRead(5) == HIGH) { // if the light is red
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);      // turn off red light
      digitalWrite(3, HIGH);     // turn on green light
      delay(500);                                   //It's this delay
    }
    else {                       // light is green
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);      // turn off green light
      digitalWrite(4, HIGH);     // turn on yellow light
      delay(500);                // yellow light turned on for a bit just like traffic light
      digitalWrite(4, LOW);      // turn off yellow light
      digitalWrite(5, HIGH);     // turn on red light
    }
  }
}
```

I thought maybe it was because I held the button for "too long" and the loop ran twice and by adding a delay I have created enough time for me to release my finger, is this the case or is there something else going on?

EDIT: without the delay it will ALWAYS jump to the else statement, even when the red light is turned on

Comment: Haven't you forgot to add a delay after `digitalWrite(5, HIGH);     // turn on red light`

Comment: What is it doing wrong when you remove the delay?

Comment: I don't need to add a delay after `digitalWrite(5, HIGH);     // turn on red light` because it will stay on until I press the button again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are having some issues with [Debouncing](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce). [more info](http://www.ladyada.net/learn/arduino/lesson5.html)

Buttons dont switch cleanly from open to closed, there is some jitter due to the mechanical nature.